# Access custom module in Azure ML subprocess / Edit PYTHONPATH inside of Azure ML pipeline

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ml-pipelines

I have the following project structure:

```
    .
    ├── my_custom_module
    │   └── __init__.py
    │   └── ...
    ├── scripts
    │   ├── start_script.py
    │   └── example.py
```

I am running `start_script.py` inside of Azure ML studio pipeline.
Inside of `start_script.py` I need to run `example.py` by using:

`subprocess.run(['python3.9', "scripts/example.py"], check=True)`.

`example.py` on the other hand needs access to `my_custom_module` (`from my_custom_module import some_class)`.

I keep getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named my_custom_module` errors, because the module is not added to the PYTHONPATH.

How do I add a custom module to the PYTHONPATH inside of Azure ML, such that it is visible by a subprocess?

Here are some debug information (I shortened some hash codes for better readability):

```
#os.getcwd() inside start_script.py and example.py returns:    
/mnt/azureml/cr/j/e9e/exe/wd 

# printing sys.path inside start_script.py and example.py returns:
/mnt/azureml/cr/j/21d/exe/wd/scripts
/azureml-envs/azureml_e9e/lib/python39.zip
/azureml-envs/azureml_e9e/lib/python3.9
/azureml-envs/azureml_e9e/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
/azureml-envs/azureml_e9e/lib/python3.9/site-packages
/mnt/azureml/cr/j/21d/exe/wd
/azureml-envs/azureml_e9e/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azureml/_project/vendor

# os.system(which python) inside start_script.py:
/azureml-envs/azureml_e9e/bin/python 
# os.system(which python) inside example.py returns nothing
```

so far I have tried to add my_custom_module to the PYTHONPATH inside of start_script.py so example.py can import it by using:

```
os.system(f"export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:{os.getcwd()}") # tested also without "$PYTHONPATH:"
os.system(f"export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:{os.getcwd() + '/my_custom_module'}") # tested also without "$PYTHONPATH:"
sys.path.append(os.getcwd() + "/my_custom_module")
```

So far, nothing had worked.
Appending it to sys.path made it show up inside of `start_script.py`, but NOT inside of `example.py`.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we cannot edit the PYTHONPATH inside the default pipeline. Instead, we can create the Data Science VM using the ARM template and make the custom modifications inside the current working directory.

**Ubuntu Based:**

```
# create a Ubuntu Data Science VM in your resource group
az vm create --resource-group YOUR-RESOURCE-GROUP-NAME --name YOUR-VM-NAME --image microsoft-dsvm:linux-data-science-vm-ubuntu:linuxdsvmubuntu:latest --admin-username YOUR-USERNAME --admin-password YOUR-PASSWORD --generate-ssh-keys --authentication-type password
```

**Windows Based:**

```
# create a Windows Server 2016 DSVM in your resource group
az vm create --resource-group YOUR-RESOURCE-GROUP-NAME --name YOUR-VM-NAME --image microsoft-dsvm:dsvm-windows:server-2016:latest --admin-username YOUR-USERNAME --admin-password YOUR-PASSWORD --authentication-type password
```

**Create a conda environment for azure machine learning**

```
**conda create -n py310 python=310**
```

**Activate and Install**

```
conda activate py310
pip install azure-ai-ml
```

**To deploy:**

To deploy the template, we need to use the following procedure mentioned in below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/data-science-virtual-machine/dsvm-tutorial-resource-manager